# Azure IoT Edge manifest ported from docker compose

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

We already have an IoT edge server, running docker container via docker compose (no builds). I've been evaluating Azure IoT Hub / IoT Edge for possibly managing these edge devices (and the containers running on them).  I see the deployment manifest (or Create Options) handle much of what's in the compose file's 'services' section.  I am new to Azure, and having trouble finding documentation on where, if anywhere, I could place the 'volumes' and 'networks' sections of my docker compose in the manifest. Any pointers would be much appreciated.
For example, my compose:

```
networks:
   myownnetwork:
       external: true

volumes:
   myownvolume:
       external: true

services:
   myowncontainer:
       image: "myown/nwoym:abc:latest"
       restart: always
       ports:
           - "123:321"
       networks:
           - "myownnetwork"
       volumes:
           - /myownvolume/config:/here/config:ro
       container_name: bob
```

In the docker compose file, at the (global) 'top level', you can specify volumes and networks. A volume specified there can be a shared volume. It's available to any/all containers to (optionally) use, referenced per container definition in the 'services' section of the compose file. Same goes for defining a non-default network. I was hoping to do something similar with Azure IoT Edge deployments. The 'Container Create Options' are container specific. I guess the question is "How can I create shared volumes for my IoT Edge modules?" & "How can I create and use  a non-default network for my IoT Edge modules".

Comment: this is not about azure, this is docker internal networks\volumes

Comment: I'm asking how to define the networks and volumes in the Azure deployment manifest.  I know how to do it in the docker compose file.

Comment: what is `azure deployment manifest`?

Comment: Referring to the Automatic Device Management for Edge IoT, trying to define my list of containers, and, hopefully, define volumes, etc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition

Comment: ok, wont be able to help you with that, sorry

Comment: In the docker compose file, at the (global) 'top level', you can specify volumes and networks. A volume specified there can be a shared volume. It's available to any/all containers to (optionally) use, referenced per container definition in the 'services' section of the compose file. Same goes for defining a non-default network. I was hoping to do something similar with IoT edge deployments. The 'Container Create Options' are container specific. I guess the question is "How can I create shared volumes for my IoT Edge modules?" & "How can I create a non-default network for my IoT Edge modules".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Create Options are basically the Docker engine API:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.32/#operation/ContainerCreate

Step 3 [here](https://github.com/veyalla/logspout-loganalytics/blob/master/README.md#configure-the-logging-module-in-iot-hub) has an example.

Comment: Thanks, Venkat, while that is helpful, it is not quite what I am looking for.  Please see the additional comment I added today to my original post.

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarifying. Creating volumes or networks at a global level to be shared across all modules is not yet supported. You might be able to use the [dockerd options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) to set something up that modules can then use, but it cannot be managed via a IoT Edge deployment json.

Comment: Thanks again, Venkat.  Mind if I ask how you came to this conclusion, what you based it on? Do you happened to be a MS employee?

Comment: Sorry, realized that I didn't update my profile. Yes, I work at Microsoft as PM for IoT Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is still in early preview, please go ahead and try this tool to convert your docker-compose.yml to deployment.json with just one command -https://github.com/VSChina/compose-to-manifest